# How do i combine multiple dataframes using a repeating index system

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, concatenation

I have multiple dataframes that I want to combine and only want to use the indexing system of the first dataframe. The problem is the indices I want to use are repeating and I want to keep it that way.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, join='inner')
```

This gives me `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Just so it's clear, `df1` has repeating indices (0-9 and then it repeats again multiple times), whereas `df2` and `df3` are single-column dataframes and have non-repeating indices. The number of rows do match though.

Comment: try join? `df1.join([df2,df3])`

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i understand your index repeats itself, on df1. That is what is causing the given error `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`, since you have a loop beetween (0,9 values) pandas, will never be able to identify which row to join with what row since the indexes well are repeated so  non unique. My apprach would be just to use join, but hey if you want to use concat for reasons

A few ways to do this would be just

Just using the join function

```
df1.join([df2,df3])
```

But if you insist on using concat, i would

```
x = df1.index
df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1,join='inner')
df.index = x
```

Comment: @INGI0RIAM0R1 here is whats happening with join, say df1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], df2 = [7, 8, 9, 10,11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ] and df3 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]..... when i do the df1.join([df2,df3])......the new df1 index becomes [0, 0, 0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2] and only includes the first three values of the other dfs. so, for df2 = 7, 8, 9  and for df3 = 20 , 21, 22 are repeated. i lose the rest of the values.